# how can I display an image created with 2htdp in a separate frame?

Tags: racket

In the Racket programming language, what is the method to display an image created with the 2htdp/image library in a separate frame?

The key points are:

2htdp/image: The image library in the Racket teaching languages
Create an image using 2htdp/image
Display that image in a separate GUI window (frame) in Racket
So in summary, the question is asking:

What is the way to take an image created with the 2htdp/image library in Racket, and display it in a separate, independent GUI frame window?

I'm in the process of creating a game similar to Catan in Racket. The ideal workflow would be to show a map made with 2htdp graphics in one frame, and handle menus and player actions in the main listener REPL. Whenever game data changes, it should update the display in the separate frame in real time.

Could you translate the above description to English for me?

this is map&status image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuy2D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

See [Racket Docs 2.2.6 Image Interoperability](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage-guide.html#%28part._.Image_.Interoperability%29). You have three options:

1. You can insert your image into `text%` or `pasteboard%` object, using [`insert`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._text%7E25%29._insert%29%29) function:

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)

(define pasteboard (new pasteboard%))

(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Example"]
                   [width 250]   
                   [height 250]))

(define editor-canvas (new editor-canvas%
                           [parent frame]
                           [editor pasteboard]))

(send frame show #t)

(define image
  (above (triangle 40 "solid" "red")
         (rectangle 40 30 "solid" "black")))

(send pasteboard insert image 25 25)
```

2. You can convert your image into `pict` with [`pict-convert`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/Conversion_to_Picts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._pict%2Fconvert..rkt%29._pict-convert%29%29), then call [`pict->bitmap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/Rendering.html#%28def._%28%28lib._pict%2Fmain..rkt%29._pict-%7E3ebitmap%29%29) and draw such bitmap. Note that you have to require another library- [pict](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/index.html).

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image
         pict/convert)
(require (only-in pict
                  pict->bitmap))

(define image
  (above (triangle 40 "solid" "red")
         (rectangle 40 30 "solid" "black")))

(define my-bitmap (pict->bitmap (pict-convert image)))

(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Example"]
                   [width 250]   
                   [height 250]))

(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]
                     [paint-callback
                      (lambda (canvas dc)
                        (send dc draw-bitmap my-bitmap 0 0))]))

(send frame show #t)
```

3. There is also low-level function [`render-image`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/mrlib/Image_Core.html#%28def._%28%28lib._mrlib%2Fimage-core..rkt%29._render-image%29%29), provided by [mrlib/image-core](https://docs.racket-lang.org/mrlib/Image_Core.html):

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image
         pict/convert)
(require (only-in pict
                  pict->bitmap)
         (only-in mrlib/image-core
                  render-image))

(define image
  (above (triangle 40 "solid" "red")
         (rectangle 40 30 "solid" "black")))

(define my-bitmap (pict->bitmap (pict-convert image)))

(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Example"]
                   [width 250]   
                   [height 250]))

(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]
                     [paint-callback
                      (lambda (canvas dc)
                        (render-image my-bitmap dc 0 0))]))

(send frame show #t)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent around 5 hours going through documentation, but I could only figure out how to load images locally - I was totally stuck. I will try implementing the method you suggested right away. If I can get this working, I'll be able to use larger maps which will really improve the look and enjoyability of the game!